# Assigning function to class property in the class' constructor?

Tags: php, laravel, constructor

I came across this code in the Laravel codebase, where a function is assigned to a property (`$this->userResolver`) within the constructor. What is the purpose of this?

The userResolver  is not using any arguments passed to the constructor. The class in question is the AuthManager class (Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php).

If I remove the $this->userResolver code here in the constructor, everything still seems to work just fine. Would love if somebody can explain this one, thanks!

```
   public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->userResolver = function ($guard = null) {
            return $this->guard($guard)->user();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that is is setting `userResolver` to point to a function. That function has a parameter ($guard). In general, this is a technique to add a function to an object.

Comment: yes it's setting a function, but why here in the constructor? why not use a normal method declaration? e.g. `public function userResolver() { //code here }}`

Comment: I don't know if there is some magical answer to this. And all it does is call some other function. So it is only a convenience.

Comment: you're likely right on no magical answer, thanks for taking time to look at this, appreciate it!